# Replace special string part in PHP

Tags: php

I need to transform this string:

```
Hello, i'm **super** and **tall**.
```

to this one:

```
Hello, i'm <big>super</big> and <big>tall</big>.
```

So I use this:

```
$string = "Hello, i'm **super** and **tall**.";
$old = array("**", "**");
$new = array("<big>", "</big>");
$newString = str_replace($old, $new, $string);
```

But it don't work.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely clean this up a bit but, this should get the job done.

```
<?php
    $string = "Hello, i'm **super** and **tall**.";
    $pattern = '/\*{2}/';
    $replacement = '<big>';
    $result =  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

    $pattern2 = '/\b(<big>)/';
    $replacement = '</big>';
    echo preg_replace($pattern2, $replacement, $result);
?>
```

I am using regex oppose to an array but, the first regex `/\*{2}/` look for 2 **. If if finds the 2 ** it will replace them with `<big>`. The second regex `\b(<big>)` will then look for all odd occurrences (or ending tags) and will replace it with the appropriate ending html tag. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate start and begin tag so str_replace can do the work with the exact accuracy you ask.
Example:

```
<?php 
$string = "Hello, i'm *begin*super*end* and *begin*tall*end*.";
$old = array('*begin*', '*end*');
$new = array("<big>", "</big>");
$newString = str_replace($old, $new, $string);

echo $newString;
?>
```